# No common application protocol between the client and server? An error when using Entrez Direct

Tags: curl, edirect

After a long time not running EDirect, I got an error when I tried using it. It said," curl: schannel: next InitializationSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0×80090367) - There is no common application protocol between the client and server...
I tried using WiFi and hotspot, but it did not work.
Additional info:
1- I ran EDirect on Cygwin64 Terminal on my personal computer with Windows 11 operating system.
2- I first ran 'export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/edirect'. After that, I tried 'esearch -db pubmed -query "stroke AND english [FILT] AND has abstract [FILT] NOT review [PTYP]" | efilter -mindate 2000 | efetch -format xml | xtract -pattern PubmedArticle -element PMID AbstractText > dm_cs.txt'

I used to ran it successfully on the same PC over WiFi or hotspot three month ago.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: i) your operating system, ii) the _exact_ command you tried to run and iii) tell us if there is anything special about your setup (are you behind a firewall? are you connecting over ssh or something similar? anything else relevant).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This happens.

1. One possibility is it's simply NCBI blocking the request to avoid being overrun by e.g. bots. This occurs if you've been running the script repeatedly within a single day. It will be fine tomorrow in this scenario.
2. The second possibility is you've not supplied an email address.
3. The final possibility is if you're running a VPN. NCBI has taken a strong dislike to VPN's *per se*, I've never figured out its algorithms - it seems to permit a fixed number of requests then pointedly refuses. Just turn off the VPN.

If its point 2 then understanding how you've coded this would be useful to allow an email address to be sent. Biopython has a function for this. I just use Biopython BTW.